# how to build a liner mixed effect model in step-wise way

Tags: r

Im simulating a method which can added groups of terms according to a fixed sequential order into liner mixed effects model use nmle() in R.
accroding to author says she divide Variables in four classes and in each of class there are some main effects and their quadratic and linear terms and first order interactions between them.
things like  `"A,B,C,D,   A^2,B^2,C^2,D^2"    A+B,B+C,C+D   A*B,B*C,C*D`

*https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/action/downloadSupplement?doi=10.1111%2F1365-2664.12478&file=jpe12478-sup-0001-SuppInfo.docx*
you can see details in **Table S2**.

In TableS2 there are interaction terms and i dont know if i should use:or* to show that relationship,also what is the meaning of + in that table.
here is the code i tired

```
mod1<-lme(C50_0.45~1,random = ~  1|sitecode,data=practice,method="ML")
mod2<-lme(C50_0.45~MAT,random = ~  1|sitecode,data=practice,method="ML")
mod3<-lme(C50_0.45~MAP,random = ~  1|sitecode,data=practice,method="ML")
mod4<-lme(C50_0.45~MGSL,random = ~  1|sitecode,data=practice,method="ML")
mod5<-lme(C50_0.45~MGDD,random = ~  1|sitecode,data=practice,method="ML")
mod6<-lme(C50_0.45~MAT+I(MAT^2),random = ~  1|sitecode,data=practice,method="ML")
mod7<-lme(C50_0.45~MAP+I(MAP^2),random = ~  1|sitecode,data=practice,method="ML")
mod8<-lme(C50_0.45~MGSL+I(MGDD^2),random = ~  1|sitecode,data=practice,method="ML")
mod9<-lme(C50_0.45~MGDD+I(MGSL^2),random = ~  1|sitecode,data=practice,method="ML")
mod10<-lme(C50_0.45~MAT+MAP,random = ~  1|sitecode,data=practice,method="ML")
mod11<-lme(C50_0.45~MGDD+MAP,random = ~  1|sitecode,data=practice,method="ML")
mod12<-lme(C50_0.45~MGSL+MAP,random = ~  1|sitecode,data=practice,method="ML")
mod13<-lme(C50_0.45~MAT*MAP,random = ~  1|sitecode,data=practice,method="ML")
mod14<-lme(C50_0.45~MGDD*MAP,random = ~  1|sitecode,data=practice,method="ML")
mod15<-lme(C50_0.45~MGSL*MAP,random = ~  1|sitecode,data=practice,method="ML")
AIC(mod1)-AIC(mod2)
AIC(mod1)-AIC(mod3)
AIC(mod1)-AIC(mod4)
...
anova(mod1,mod2)
anova(mod1,mod3)
anova(mod1,mod4)
...
```

this was the way i tried  to test in AIC() until find terms which down AIC and significant in chi-squared **likelihood ratio deletion test(LRT)** then combine these term to be a new model. after these tests," another set of variables representing different controls over function were then added and the process was repeated."

but i cant replay the result which author did in **Table S3-6**

here is data https://datadryad.org/stash/dataset/doi:10.5061/dryad.s7867
(Manning et al. 2015).

**FIRST**
For example

```
mod3<-lme(C50_0.45~MAP,random = ~  1|sitecode,data=practice,method="ML")
mod7<-lme(C50_0.45~MAP+I(MAP^2),random = ~  1|sitecode,data=practice,method="ML")
mod10<-lme(C50_0.45~MAT+MAP,random = ~  1|sitecode,data=practice,method="ML")
mod11<-lme(C50_0.45~MGDD+MAP,random = ~  1|sitecode,data=practice,method="ML")
mod12<-lme(C50_0.45~MGSL+MAP,random = ~  1|sitecode,data=practice,method="ML")
mod13<-lme(C50_0.45~MAT*MAP,random = ~  1|sitecode,data=practice,method="ML")
mod14<-lme(C50_0.45~MGDD*MAP,random = ~  1|sitecode,data=practice,method="ML")
mod15<-lme(C50_0.45~MGSL*MAP,random = ~  1|sitecode,data=practice,method="ML")
AIC(mod1)-AIC(mod3)
[1] 6.281076
AIC(mod1)-AIC(mod7)
[1] 4.440664
AIC(mod1)-AIC(mod10)
[1] 4.319208
AIC(mod1)-AIC(mod11)
[1] 4.390488
AIC(mod1)-AIC(mod12)
[1] 4.332252
AIC(mod1)-AIC(mod13)
[1] 3.261881
AIC(mod1)-AIC(mod14)
[1] 3.205841
AIC(mod1)-AIC(mod15)
[1] 4.132244
```

All these models are significant in LRT But if I retain those term in model,the MAP in mod3 are the same as MAP in mod7,10,11,12,13,14,15 and the first class final model like this

```
mods1<-lme(C50_0.45 ~MAP+MAP+I(MAP^2)+MAT+MAP+MGDD+MAP+MGDD+MAP+MGSL+MAP+MAT:MAP+MGDD*MAP+MGDD*MAP+MGSL*MAP,random = ~  1|sitecode,data=practice,method="ML")
```

i dont know if it is right to start LRT because for example, delete (MGSL+MAP)OR(MAT+MAP) is just like the same as only delete MGSL OR MAT

**SECOND** As you can see in data I dont know how to add **type** in the way author describe in table S2 and it may be the reason i cant reproduce the right final model

about my model  because of those problem, i've tried but you know sometimes delete the necessary terms or just cant delete some unnecessary terms.And in C50_250 or in total C I may reproduce the same final model as in table  but it didnt work in other.

Comment: There will be various ways to do this in R. To get a helpful answer you will need to be more specific with your question. What approach are you trying, and where is it getting stuck?

Comment: @rw2 thank you for your advise  I've edit my question more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the values in Table S3 using the model below. Perhaps this will help you figure out how to reproduce the rest of their approach. `data` refers to the raw table as read in from the link you provided.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lme4)
practice <- dplyr::filter(data, datatype=="Initial")
model <- lme4::lmer(TotalC ~ MAT + I(MAT^2) + moist + I(moist^2) + PH + I(PH^2) + (1|site), data=practice)
```

I assume that the response is different for each of the models referred to in tables S3 to S6. S3 seems to use TotalC, but presumably C250, C50-250 etc are the responses for the other models.

In answer to your question about specifying interaction terms, this link is very useful for understanding how to specify formulas in R:
https://conjugateprior.org/2013/01/formulae-in-r-anova/

In short, A * B is equivalent to A + B + A:B

Comment: thanks.  yes totalC is tableS3, and S4 is C250,S5 is C50_250,S6 is C50_0.45.  I may asked a incomplete question. the point is if i use the right process to reproduce the result. I know  A * B is equivalent to A + B + A:B.  Actually each tableS3~S6 is a formula,   i presum it is  a step wise way to add terms in model, but i dont know if i should add them one term by one from a class and retain significant terms or add whole class once as in table S2.  by the way fixed sequence is 1.Climate,2.soil physical and chemical properties,3.Management,4.Plant functional traits (CWMs).

Comment: It looks like they used a stepwise process - and the process you described with the code in your question looks consistent with what they did, as far as it goes. After each model they kept terms if they were significant and improved the AIC. What is your question - do you end up with a different final model? If so, what is your model? or is it a question about how to run the selection process?

Comment: Sorry to bother you,i've add details about my questions, you can check it  now. thank you

Comment: In mods1 you're specifying the same term multiple times, which seems odd. As to the precise order in which they've selected terms, I can't really follow from the paper - it is a method specific to that study, rather than a common statistical method. You might be best off emailing the corresponding author of the paper if you still can't reproduce their results.

Comment: Thank you  very much for nearly two days guide to me,and I really learnd a lot. I will emailing the corresponding author and try my best to figure out this method. thank you